сравнить данные одной таблицы столбца с другой таблицей столбца , первичный ключ в первой таблице , база mariadb
сравнить данные одной таблицы столбца с другой таблицей столбца , первичный ключ в первой таблице , база mariadb .
Это база Радиус . Идут расхождения в колонке radcheck.username и radusergroup.username
Надо сравнить и удалить ненужные записи в radusergroup.username

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

DELETE .. WHERE NOT EXISTS.
